# Laravel 5.8 and PHP version 7.3 - Cannot install spatie laravel-query-builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-query-builder

I'm running a `laravel-5.8`-application and I want to install the `spatie/laravel-query-builder`, but for some reason, when I run

```
composer require spatie/laravel-query-builder
```

I get some errors:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.0
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
> - spatie/laravel-query-builder 3.2.0 requires illuminate/database ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database...

And I have no clue why, since I do have requirements due to the documentation page https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v3/requirements - I have PHP 7.3 and Laravel 5.8

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Since they say it supports Laravel 5.8, open a ticket. Either they need to revert the changes made to their composer.json 24 days ago, or they need to fix their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package seems to be looking fo `Laravel v6` or greater. If you look at Packagist - https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/framework#v5.8.0, You can see that 5.8.0 of Laravel installs `illuminate/database` v5.8.0

Seems like you may need to contact Spatie or raise a bug ticket

Comment: Upgrading helped, but I needed to modify some things in my application. Yeah, I might raise a ticket. Thanks for your help anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation must be outdated, because the latest `composer.json` released to this date (v3.2.4, here: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder/blob/3.2.4/composer.json) requires at least php 7.3 and Laravel 6

```json
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "illuminate/database": "^6.0|^7.0|^8.0",
        "illuminate/http": "^6.0|^7.0|^8.0",
        "illuminate/support": "^6.0|^7.0|^8.0"
    },
```